# C/C++ Output preprocess file always failed

Tags: c++, linker-errors, preprocessor

A very simple source code like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ADD(x,y) x+y

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
printf("%d\n",ADD(1,2));
return 0;
}
```

And the `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(url_email LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_compile_options(-E -v)

add_executable(url_email main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(url_email)
```

I try to output the preprocess file like url_email.i but the linker always say:

```
/usr/bin/ld:CMakeFiles/url_email.dir/main.cpp.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
```

What's the problem it is?

I try to output the preprocess file like url_email.i which include the processed macro define

Comment: CMake is trying to build an executable as you asked it to with `add_executable`. But with the `-E -v` options the compiler doesn't actually compile anything. I am not sure whether you can use CMake to build preprocessed source code files at all. What's the goal here overall?

Comment: Unless you tell it otherwise, CMake is taking the path of least resistance from source files to executable, and that's source-> compiled objects-> executable. It doesn't quite clue in to the fact that one of your custom compiler options told the compiler to spit out a preprocessor file rather than a compiled object. The generated makefile will still expect a .o file and will name your .i file accordingly. Obviously the linker doesn't much like that idea.

Comment: the compiler didnt manage to create an executable, but so what? The output of `-E` should be generated, is it not?

Comment: please read description of tags when unsure if they apply. `e` and `compiler-construction` are both offtopic.

Comment: I know enough CMake to get by, but I've never asked it for preprocessor files. Normally when I want one of these I just run the compiler manually, but odds are good that CMake has automated it and that googling something like "CMake output preprocess files" will get you on the right path faster than camping out and waiting for a new Stackoverflow answer. Odds are really good you'll find an existing Stackoverflow answer that helps you out.

Comment: Instead of adding special rules to ythe CMakelists.txt file, have you simply tried doing a 'make main.cpp.i' to use the built-in CMake-generated  target?

Answer (score 0):

Seems with -E option the object file (main.cpp.o) already changed to ASCII format and expended the macro define, there is no url_email.i file anymore.
Thanks for everyone's answer.

```
extern void funlockfile (FILE *__stream) noexcept (true);
# 885 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int __uflow (FILE *);
extern int __overflow (FILE *, int);
# 902 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
}
# 2 "/home/hwb/Project/url_email/main.cpp" 2

# 5 "/home/hwb/Project/url_email/main.cpp"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n",1 +2);

    return 0;
}
```